# git clone https runs error

Tags: git, cocoapods

I get an error when I use `git clone https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git`

The error info is

```
Cloning spec repo `master` from `https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git` (branch `master`)
$ /usr/local/bin/git clone https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git master
Cloning into 'master'...
fatal: remote error:
  %s is not a valid repository name
  Email support@github.com for help
[!] Unable to add a source with url `https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git` named `master`.
(/usr/local/bin/git clone https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git master

Cloning into 'master'...
fatal: remote error:
  %s is not a valid repository name
  Email support@github.com for help
)
```

You can try adding it manually in `~/.cocoapods/repos` or via `pod repo add`.

But when I use `git clone git@github.com:CocoaPods/CocoaPods.git`, it is successful. How can I fix this?

The `Podfile` is here

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'ApiTest' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!
  pod 'SnapKit', '~> 3.0.0'
  pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.0'
  pod 'Kingfisher','~> 3.0.1'
  # Pods for ApiTest

  target 'ApiTestTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  target 'ApiTestUITests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

Comment: Please post the error in the question, not via a link.

Comment: And preferably as text, rather than an image

Comment: Could just be a transient error, `pod setup` runs past the point of failure successfully for me.

Comment: I guess there is something wrong with you Podfile, could you pasted in the answer?